# PHP 7.2 + Laravel 5.8: Call to parent method defined in Trait overwritten by a call to parent method in a Class that uses this Trait

Tags: php, laravel

It may be hard to explain this case via title so let me put it here.

I had to use Laravel Boilerplate. It uses UUIDs for models. It has a `trait`  that when User model is being created, it adds UUID.

```
protected static function boot() // this is in the trait
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = PackageUuid::generate(4)->string;
    });
}
```

My Eloquent `User` uses this trait. Everything was working but one day I had to add global scope to `User` **so I defined in the User class**:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new UserScopeSalesContactAdmin());
}
```

[image]

I totally missed that. Now my global scope works but UUID is ignored. **I obviously know why this happens**. I'm not the author of the Boilerplate and I would architecture this in a different way but it's a nice educational case hence my question:

**How can I change my code the way that both my global scope works as well as UUID?** I could simply move my `addGlobalScope` to the trait but it's obviously stupid idea as scope has nothing to do with UUID hence it violates the OOP rule.

edit:

I did other way around: I copied:

```
static::creating(function ($model) {
     $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = PackageUuid::generate(4)->string;
});
```

to the `boot` method in the `User` but still I consider this as a duplication…

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own trait. But instead of `boot()` define `boot<TraitName>()`:

```
trait HasUuid
{
    protected static function bootHasUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = PackageUuid::generate(4)->string; 
        });
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to override `boot()`.

Laravel will call the special boot method of traits based on the naming scheme described above. It's just not well documented functionality...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this assuming the name of the trait is BoilerplateTrait. Call the BoilerplateTrait boot function from inside the boot function of you User model

```
protected static function boot()
{
    //parent::boot();
    BoilerplateTrait::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new UserScopeSalesContactAdmin());
}
```